# Testing Firebase rules in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-admin

I am setting up integration tests for my model layer and Firebase rules. All written in TypeScript. A basic test example is something like this:

```
it('should not be able to write to his own public profile with occupied user name', (done) => {
  const id = new UserID(testUser.uid);
  const validPublicProfile = new UserPublicProfile(id, 'occupied_user_name', new Timestamp(), 'testUser');
  const ref = UserPublicProfile.reference(id);
  firebaseModule.writeToRef(ref, validPublicProfile)
    .then((snap) => {
      expect(true).to.be.false;
      done();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      expect(err.code).to.equal(PERMISSION_DENIED_ERROR_CODE);
      done();
    });
}).timeout(TEST_TIMEOUT);
```

This creates a public profile and gives it the user name `occupied_user_name`.

When I set up my tests I would like to use the admin SDK to set up a predefined database, that e.g. has a user in it with the user name `occupied_user_name`.

So, I need the admin SDK to setup the database, and the client SDK to test the rules. When I am using both the admin SDK and the client SDK I get this error:

`FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times. Please make sure the format of the database URL matches with each database() call.`

I simply found where the error was being thrown in the firebase package (`node_modues/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/RepoManager.js -> line 116`) and commented it out. Now I can run my tests and they all work just as expected.

However, I am setting up CircleCI on my database now, and it can not run the tests because of the `Datanase initialized multiple times.` error.

I have a file called `firebaseClient.ts` that looks like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import * as firebaseProjectManager from './../../functions/firebaseProjectManager'

const config = firebaseProjectManager.getClientConfig();
firebase.initializeApp(config)
const database = firebase.database();

export function deleteFromRef(ref) {
  return database
    .ref(ref)
    .remove();
}
.
.
.
```

And a `firebaseAdmin.ts` file that looks something like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as firebaseProjectManager from './../../functions/firebaseProjectManager'
const databaseExample = require('./../database_example.json');

let rootID: string

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseProjectManager.getAdminCert()),
  databaseURL: firebaseProjectManager.getDatabaseURL(),
});

const adminDb = admin.database();

export default admin

export function setUpTestRoot() {
  return adminDb.ref().push(databaseExample)
    .then((snap) => {
      rootID = snap.key;
      return rootID;
    });
}
.
.
.
```

And in my tests, I set up the database with the `firebaseAdmin.ts` file and then modify the database with the `firebaseClient.ts` file.

Am I going about this the wrong way? or am I forced to fork the firebase repo, uncomment the line that throws the error, and use that instead?

Comment: Could you show exactly how you are using both SDKs together?  Are you ever calling initializeApp()?  It's worth noting that with Android, you can't use both the client and admin SDK together.

Comment: I edited the question with some more details.

Comment: Try using initializeApp to create a named, non-default instance of App, and pass that around to admin SDK APIs.  Maybe then it won't collide with the client SDK?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_multiple_apps

Comment: Yes! that did the trick! Thank you so much! Wired that the admin SDK and the client SDK are so attached.